# Mechanize converts - char to â€“

Tags: utf-8, mechanize

I am using Mechanize to read a web page at http://www.daz3d.com/pirates-black-pearl.

The page seems to read OK, but for some reason some characters are translated differently.

For example, there is a

in the product description that looks like this when I view the source of the page in firefox:

```
<p>Pirates – Black Pearl is a high quality conforming clothing from Pretty3D. Designed specifically for Victoria 4, Pirates – Black Pearl is a complete conforming outfit that includes a Dress, Corset, Panty, Boots, Necklace, Pistol Holder, and Seven Props.</p>
```

But, when I look at what was downloaded by Mechanize, I see this:

```
<p>Pirates â€“ Black Pearl is a high quality conforming clothing from Pretty3D. Designed specifically for Victoria 4, Pirates â€“ Black Pearl is a complete conforming outfit that includes a Dress, Corset, Panty, Boots, Necklace, Pistol Holder, and Seven Props.</p>
```

Note the - is replaced by â€“.

The charset is set to utf-8 in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

This happens with a number of charactors that should be common ASCII.

What's happening here, and how do I fix it?

I know it is a unicode issue, but not how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a hyphen; that's an endash, which is a dash roughly the same width as the letter N (the origin of the name).

Endash has a Unicode code point of u+2013 (hex), which translates into three octets (bytes) in UTF-8, so that looks just about right if you're mistakenly treating the content as ASCII.

There's also an Emdash (based on the width of M) at u+2014.

The fix is really to respect the encoding of the page that you're working with; if it says it's UTF-8, make sure you parse the page with that encoding. There are a number of Unicode codepoints that look similar to ASCII characters that are not identical. Some of them exist for compatibility with legacy encodings, and some exist because a strong enough case was made that they were substantially distinct characters (including some traditional ligatures that have come to be known as distinct characters).

There is a conversion that some mappings enable called a "best fit conversion", in which characters that are "close enough" (by some definition) to the target encoding are selected instead of using the "default" mapping (usually a question mark or unknown character mark), but I only recommend that for dealing with certain legacy encodings. UTF-8 has been easy to deal with in most environments for 14-18 years, so it shouldn't be a burden to do it right.

Comment: OK...is this something the site would have encoded on purpose? And for what reason? Pardon me if I am a bit dense here, but how do I fix this in Python? If this is the only char it does this on I can do a replace, but I expect there may be other chars this happens with...

Comment: Sure, why not? Emdashes are automatically inserted by many word processors when you type two hyphens in a row, and there are a number of typographical reasons to use Endashes, too. There are a bunch of characters that you might not find important that a typographer would.

Comment: I've only used Mechanize in Ruby, so I'm not sure what the correct solution is in Python, but probably the normal UTF-8 parsing methods. Something like myhtml.decode('utf-8'), perhaps?

Comment: So it would be some kind of encode/decode situation after the read? Or can I set Mechanize to do this automatically? I remember doing something like this a couple of years ago, I'll try to track that code down and see what I did then. Thanks...

Comment: I think beautifulsoup mostly automatically handles the encoding if you're using it to parse the HTML (it won't know about http Content-Type headers that can specify the encoding, probably, so you may have to inspect those yourself). Like I wrote above, in a pinch, I think that .decode should do the trick if you're not using a full on HTML parsing library.